# Added subview is positioned slightly off - how can I get it back into place?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

**UPDATE: Solved! While the contentMode for pianoNoteDisplayed and piano_background were indeed the same, apparently this wasn't true for the added subviews. I simply added the line subview.contentMode = superview.contentMode to the function vdmzz suggested, and now everything looks right on all 4 screen sizes.**

There are two image views: one called "piano_background" holds a background image (a piano keyboard) and the other will be used to display highlighted notes. The second is constrained to the first:

[image: constraints] (the width constraint is probably unnecessary, because the leading and trailing constraints are already set, right?)

To display multiple highlighted keys, I am programmatically adding subviews to the piano_note view and activating the NSLayoutConstraints to get it into place (otherwise it shows up way out of position) like so:

```
pianoNoteDisplayed.image = nil

if !notesAlreadyAttempted.contains(currentUserAnswer) {

   let wrongNoteImageName = "large_\(currentUserAnswer)_wrong"
   let wrongNoteImage = UIImage(named: wrongNoteImageName)
   let wrongNoteImageView = UIImageView(image: wrongNoteImage!)

   wrongNoteImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   pianoNoteDisplayed.addSubview(wrongNoteImageView)

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       wrongNoteImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pianoNoteDisplayed!.frame.width),
       wrongNoteImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pianoNoteDisplayed!.frame.height)
   ])

   }

   notesAlreadyAttempted.append(currentUserAnswer)
}
```

The issue is that the subview is displayed slightly off, and I can't seem to figure out why:

[image: subview slightly off] 
(as you can see, the highlight looks slightly compressed vertically.. the top lands correctly, but the bottom doesn't reach far enough by about 5px)

I have tried centering and constraining the subview in multiple ways, using suggestions from about 5 different answers on stack, and a few other articles I found. The images I am using (the piano background and the overlaying note highlight subview) are identical sizes. I have tried adding more or fewer constraints in the interface builder, and I have tried adding subviews to the original piano_background view instead of the second pianoNoteDisplayed view - same result. Using the pianoNoteDisplayed view itself to display the highlighted note works fine by the way:

[image: image displaying correctly 1]

[image: image displaying correctly 2]

And these are displayed using the usual .image method:

```
pianoNoteDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: "large_\(currentCorrectAnswer)_right")
```

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot the issue further?

Comment: I suspect your problem is the centerY constraint to the safe area because the safe area isn't centered on the screen in all cases.  If the images are the same dimensions, then set leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints equal and make sure the `contentMode`s for the imageViews are the same.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for the suggestion! This is what I used to have (seems most logical to me as well) before I started changing things to try to find a solution. Changing it back doesn't seem to help though unfortunately: https://imgur.com/EDLoAvc ... Any other suggestions for things I could try? I suppose I could create a separate view for every possible wrong note highlight that could be displayed, but this seems unnecessarily clunky. I've got another level in this game with a different background image, but virtually identical code and settings otherwise that works perfectly with subviews.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I don't think constraints are your problem.

Comment: You're probably right. A sanity check in Sketch shows that putting the note highlight image on top of the background image works perfectly: https://imgur.com/JadvESN & https://imgur.com/ZyE5dPP ... They are the same size after all, so duh... And the pianoNoteDisplayed image view and its subviews are perfectly constrained to the piano_background image view in IB and programmatically, so why in the world wouldn't they line up? There's gotta be a simple reason; can't wait to discover it :)

Comment: Have you tried having a look at it using Debug View Hierarchy? There might be some clues there as to whether the view is the right size and/or the image is being drawn incorrectly for some reason...

Comment: @Matvey - add your individual images to your question, along with a full description of constraints set on each.

Comment: @MaxChuquimia Omg, I think I fixed it. Still not sure what the issue was, but I think it was some kind of a weird constraint situation with the piano_background. I deleted all the constraints on it and re-did it, and now it's working perfectly. Strange how pianoNoteDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: "large_(currentCorrectAnswer)_right worked fine before... But now everything works smoothly, yay! It was after I spent about an hour messing with Debug View Hierarchy per your suggestion. I'm a n00b with DVH, but I noticed something was off with the frame, which prompted me to re-do the constraints.

Comment: @DonMag and anyone else -- what do you guys think I should do with the bounty? Will it be automatically awarded to vdmzz for his answer, or should I do it manually? He did help...

Comment: @Matvey - as far as I know, the bounty is awarded to the Accepted answer. No need to accept an answer if it did not solve the issue (the bounty will simply expire).

Comment: @DonMag ok, thanks! and crap, spoke too soon: the problem went away for 9.7", 10.5", and 12.9" ipads, but it's still there on the 11"... gotta keep messing with those constraints...

Comment: @Matvey - if you add your source images and constraints to your question I can take a look at what's going on.

Comment: @DonMag Source images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qjnVARY5iy4Bh-l_VngDoCjVBzcE13zS?usp=sharing Constraints: piano_background (which holds the image called "notes_on_staff_piano_background.png") is constrained to Superview via top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints. The other view called pianoNoteDisplayed (to which I'm adding subviews with images like the one called "large_E3_wrong.png") is constrained to piano_background the same way, top, bottom, leading, and trailing.

Comment: @Matvey - it doesn't appear to be a problem with your images... Double-check and make sure all your imageViews have the same `.contentMode` setting.

Comment: @DonMag you & vdmzz (see below) are on point! While the contentMode for pianoNoteDisplayed and piano_background were indeed the same, apparently this wasn't true for the added subviews. I simply added the line subview.contentMode = superview.contentMode to the function vdmzz suggested, and now everything looks right on all 4 screen sizes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as far as I understood `pianoNoteDisplayed` doesn't need to be an UIImageView.
Secondly, if you align `piano_background` and `pianoNoteDisplayed` by top, leading, trailing and bottom edges, one will be exactly on top of other. Or you could set them equal height, width and center positions.
The problem with your current set of constraints is that `piano_background`'s Y position is determined by Safe Area and therefore might defer from `pianoNoteDisplayed`'s Y position.

Try using this function:

```
func addSameSize(subview: UIView, onTopOf superview: UIView) {
    superview.addSubview(subview)

    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    subview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    subview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    subview.contentMode = superview.contentMode
}
```

E.g.

```
addSameSize(subview: wrongNoteImageView, onTopOf: pianoNoteDisplayed)
```

It  will add your image views exactly aligned on top of `pianoNoteDisplayed` view

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I get the same result with this... Using a separate function like this is definitely cleaner, so it's still an improvement :)

Comment: You mentioned that "pianoNoteDisplayed doesn't need to be an UIImageView" -- do you think this is critical? I am using it as an UIImageView in a few other parts of the code (like this, for example: pianoNoteDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: "large_\(currentCorrectAnswer)_right") because there I only need to display a single image.

Comment: Also, I haven't changed any of the constraints on the storyboard because I'm assuming that programmatic constraints override those -- is this correct?

Comment: Omg, I think I fixed it. Still not sure what the issue was, but I think it was some kind of a weird constraint situation with the piano_background. I deleted all the constraints on it and re-did it, and now it's working perfectly. Strange how pianoNoteDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: "large_(currentCorrectAnswer)_right worked fine before... But now everything works smoothly, yay!

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem :) 
> You mentioned that "pianoNoteDisplayed doesn't need to be an UIImageView" -- do you think this is critical? 
No it is not critical, just a little note :)

Comment: >Also, I haven't changed any of the constraints on the storyboard because I'm assuming that programmatic constraints override those -- is this correct?
Afaik, in your case they don't. The constraints that you are adding programatically are related to wrongNoteImageView and it's superview. And those constraints that you added in storyboard are related to piano_background and pianoNoteDisplayed

Comment: Gotcha. As I mentioned in the comments to the question, turns out I spoke too soon: the problem went away for 9.7", 10.5", and 12.9" iPads, but it's still there on the 11"...

Comment: If you are pretty sure that your constraints are correct you may want to check if your UIImageViews contentMode is the same.

Comment: Woohoo! The contentMode for pianoNoteDisplayed and piano_background were indeed the same, however apparently this wasn't true for the added subviews. I simply added the line `subview.contentMode = superview.contentMode` to the function you suggested, and now everything looks right on all 4 screen sizes. Thank you!